# Check if there is a image1 inside image2

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uiimage

I'm working in one IOS app that I should take a photo and after that checks if there is a specific image inside this photo.

IS there any way to do that? Any framework?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about (Augmented reality)

[here is wonderful tutorial from raywonderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/40870/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-marker-tracking)